# Online SharePoint file uploader

Tags: document-library, web-services, document, file-upload

I'm planning to create an web file upload to SharePoint for a web application currently under development . The idea is the user would provide the endpoint to his SharePoint server, provide username/password and the app would get a list of the folders in his document library. User then would select where to upload document, provide the file and the tool would perform the upload. The SharePoint endpoint is not known (is user input). We can assume will be used with valid endpoints.

Authentication will be oauth based. App is going to be in php, so probably would need to access SharePoint web services, but not sure what functionality I should expect, my question is: Is there a way to achieve this?. I'm open to any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of SharePoint there is no secure way to do this as SahrePoint doesn't support OAuth.

But with the upcomming SharePoint 2013 this is very possible. By defining your App as a SharePoint App, which is just a manifest describing the rights needed and your apps location. When users activate your SharePoint app it'll get the location of the SharePoint site collection as well as an OAuth token for accessing it with the rights from that user.

Comment: Is there any way to allow external access to a sharepoint server (i.e. my app runs on the cloud), but would like to allow specifying a sharepoint server address and perform the interaction authenticating users, if oauth is not possible without installing something on user's server I'm ok, I would use another mechanism (windows based auth. for example). is it possible, or am I missin something?

Comment: SharePoint has several web service as well as a very advanced client side object model (but this requires .net or JavaScript). But there requires authentication using the model defined for the web application, which can be windows or SAML claims, but I wouldn't like my users to give their credentials to a third party service. OAuth might be possible by adding code to the servers, but if your App is going to be developed now I'd recommend developing it for the just released preview version of SharePoint 2013